# Image's mipmap property isn't working in iOS

Tags: ios, qt, qml, qt5, qtquick2

The property `mipmap` `Image` just doesn't seems to be working in iOS, while working okay in Android. It seems to be an issue for OS X as well.

Below are screenshot from iOS and Android respectively.

**iOS**:

[image: Icons with mipmap on iOS]

**Android**:

[image: Icons with mipmap on Android]

I'm declaring my images like this:

```
Image {
    mipmap: true
    fillMode: Image.PreserveAspectFit

    source: "path/to/source.png"
    sourceHeight: someRelativeSize
}
```

I'm working with Qt 5.5 and testing on iOS 8.4.1 and Android 5.0 .
I don't think it about specific version of Qt/OS, because I recall to have this very issue in the past.

Using `height` instead of `sourceHeight` yields better result on iOS. Although, it's still not as good as on Android.

Comment: I don't think it's a `mipmap` issue. More likely `sourceHeight: someRelativeSize` is the problem here. You should be sure to take in account retina displays density: use images of double the size (or show them half the size they are). Try [this code](http://pastebin.com/embed_iframe.php?i=ZSgUkFQN).